# Difference between jquery ajax jsonp and angularjs $http json

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax, jsonp, mailchimp

I'm trying to migrate a feature which was written in jquery to angularjs. So instead of using jquery's ajax method, I am trying to use angularjs' $http method. The code allows a user to sign up for a mailchimp newsletter. Interestingly, when I use the jquery method, there are no issues. However, when I use the angularjs method, I get a 404 error, even though I can see in the network requests that a response from mailchimp is available. What am I doing wrong with angularjs?

I will post the two snippets of code bellow:

### AngularJS

```
 $http({
    method: "JSONP",
    url:
      "https://XXX.us4.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json? 
       u=XXX&amp&id=XXX&c=?",
    params: { EMAIL: this.text },
  }).then(
    function successCallback(response) {
      console.log("success");
      console.log(response);
    },
    function errorCallback(response) {
      console.log("error");
      console.log(response);
    }
  );
```

### jQuery ajax

```
  function successCallback(resp) {
    console.log(resp);
  }

  $.ajax({
    url:
      "https://XXX.us4.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json? 
       u=XXX&amp&id=XXX&c=?",
    data: { EMAIL: this.text },
    success: successCallback,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    error: function(resp, text) {
      console.log("mailchimp ajax submit error: " + text);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: I can't help specifically, but to diagnose the issue look at both requests in the network tab of dev tools and look for differences.

Answer (score 1):

From the Docs:

> Note that, since JSONP requests are sensitive because the response is given full access to the browser, the url must be declared, via [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) as a trusted resource URL. You can trust a URL by adding it to the whitelist via [$sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$sceDelegateProvider#resourceUrlWhitelist) or by explicitly trusting the URL via [$sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#trustAsResourceUrl).

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $http Service API Reference - jsonp Method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp)